# Skewed volumetric data with OpenGL glTexture3D with different texture dimensions

Tags: c++, opengl, boost, rendering

I have a problem to figure out how to correctly use glTexImage3D when width, height and depth are different values.
I've thought that in order to avoid 3 `new` on triple pointers and then be very careful to `delete` everything, `boost::multiarray` could have been very useful, so I've used.

```
boost::multi_array<GLubyte, 3> texture3DVolume;
texture3DVolume.resize(boost::extents[textureSizeX][textureSizeY][textureSizeZ]);

glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glGenTextures(1, &(this->textureID));
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, this->textureID);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_3D);
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, this->textureSizeX,this->textureSizeY, this->textureSizeZ,  0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture3DVolume.data());

int textureSizeX=512;
int textureSizeY=512
int textureSizeZ=511;
```

with 511 I get a skewed texture. The texture coordinates are made with a very simple shader, for every vertex (the vertices of a `[-0.5,0.5]x[-0.5,0.5]x[-0.5,0.5]` cube) I use:

```
// vertex shader...
texture_coordinate = (v.xyz+vec3(1.0))*0.5;
// then in the fragment shader
gl_FragColor = texture(my_color_texture, texture_coordinate);
```

but my result is skewed. I really don't know if I have a problem on how the data are laid out with `boost::multiarray` or what...
My result is the following:

[image: This is a view of what should be a cube where the sides are covered with spheres coming from volumetric dataset]

As you see the spheres are skewed and this is because the `width==height` but they are `!=depth`. I would like to better understand if this is a problem of how the data are laid out and/or strides.

If I set `depth=512` I get the correctly proportioned cube.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I've thought that in order to avoid 3 new on triple pointers and then be very careful to delete everything, boost::multiarray could have been very useful, so I've used.

Either is wrong. A 3 stage `new`-ed array is actually a tree. It's an array of pointers to arrays of pointers to values. What you want is a flat region of data. Don't bother with multidimensional arrays, because you don't know how those arrange the data internally.

Use a simple 1-dimensional array of length `width * height * depth`. Also make sure you set the right GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, usually 1.

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking to make that way. The only problem is the correct indexing. For a flat array like this:

`texture3DVolume = new GLubyte[textureSizeX*textureSizeY*textureSizeZ ];`

how can you index it as if it were a `[x][y][z]`?

Comment: @datenwolf Nearly, it's  `[height * width * z + width * y + x]` or `[width * (height * z + y) + x]`.

Comment: @ChristianRau: Opps, you're right. @linello: Exercise, take a piece of grid paper, draw a 16×16 rectangle and write the numbers 0 to 15 into it starting at the bottom left, work toward the right, then up. In general to index a multidimensional array you use `[d_(n-1) * d_(n-2) * d_(n-...) * x_n + d_(n-2) * d_n(n-...) * x_(n-1) + ...]`, in case of 3d array `[height * width * z + width * y + x]`

Comment: I've managed to allocate the memory as `texture3DVolume = new GLubyte[ textureSizeX*textureSizeY*textureSizeZ ];` and I accessed it as `texture3DVolume[textureSizeY* textureSizeX* z + textureSizeX* y + x];` but I still have problems of skewing when `textureSizeZ` is `!=` than `textureSizeX` and `textureSizeY`. Is this something related to the pixel alignment?

Comment: @linello: Yes, this is likely the case. Please have a look at http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glPixelStore.xml  most importantly the GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT parameter (glPixelStore should be set right before submitting data with glTexImage, glTexSubImage).

Comment: `glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT,1);` has solved my problems, no more skewing. I've also modified the shader in order to sample the `z` axis of the texture:

`texture_coordinate = vec3(((v.xy+1.0)*0.5),((v.z+1.0)*0.5)*zToXYTextureRatio);`

where `zToXyTextureRatio` is in my case `511.0/512.0` i.e. the depth of the texture divided by its width (or height).